# CSS for phone and computer browsers

Tags: css

I need some help with CSS stylesheet
Please look at this website:
http://m.facebook.com

When I open this in a phone browser, it spreads across the entire screen. Left to right. That is how I want it in my CSS.
When I open this in a computer browser, it centers itself in the middle. Something like 600px wide. I also want this in my CSS.
 This happens in all browsers like IE, firefox, chrome etc.

How can I do this?

My CSS is like this:
It works on computer browser, but doesn't spread across the screen on phone browsers...
Phone browser also shows it as a small centered content with lots of empty screen on both sides...

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
body{ margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
#page{ width: 600px; }
</style>
</head><body><center>
<div id="page">

All other content goes here

</div>
</center></body></html>
```

Comment: Learn about [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put this in your head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

if you want center it on PC browser you need this css code:

```
#page { width:100%;}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    #page { 
        width:600px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this works for mobile screen with #page{ width: 100% } However, if I use this, the website stretches on the PC browser as well. Entire screen left to right. I want it to center on PC with width:600px. Please check the link I posted. Both on PC and on phone. That is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably use an internal style, it should look something like the code below

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    div#wrapper {
        width: 400px;
    }

    div#header {
        background-image: url(media-queries-phone.jpg);
        height: 93px;
        position: relative;
    }

    div#header h1 {
        font-size: 140%;
    }

    #content {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #navigation {
        float:none;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have a doubt. I'm using width:600px in my css, and it still doesn't stretch enough on a phone browser. Even with 600px I get a lot of empty screen on the phone browser. What I want is for the webpage to use max width of 600px on a PC browser, and a full stretch on the phone browser. If I use width:100%, then it stretches full screen on both browsers, which is good for phone, but too wide for PC browser (where I just want to display in a small 600px area). What changes do I need to make in my CSS I posted above? Thanks

Comment: You need to use the auto setting instead of a defined screen size, the only time a px number should be used is to define the maximum size a mobile version of your page should be rendered in